# lme4 singular fit non randomized design

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, singular-matrix

I am analyzing a dataset with lme4. I am investigating the effects on vine yield of 5 different "Treat". We are working on-farm and we were not offered the possibility of a randomized design. So we are left with three pseudoreplicates "Rep". To get around this we did an extensive soil sampling. The idea was to study the soil variability in each pseudoreplicate (factor= "soil_cluster") and include it in a mixed model as a random effect nested in the Rep.  We found that 12 out of the 15 experimental units (5 Treat x 3 Rep) have the same soil_cluster.

I am trying to fit the following models:

```
m=lmer(yield~1+(1|Rep/soil_cluster), data=YMT,REML=FALSE)

m1=lmer(yield ~Treat +(1|Rep/soil_cluster), data=YMT,REML=FALSE)
anova(m,m1)
VarCorr(m)
VarCorr(m1)
```

I got 0.00 variance for both models

> ```
>  VarCorr(m)
>   Groups           Name        Std.Dev.
>   soil_cluster:Rep (Intercept)   0.00  
>   Rep              (Intercept) 215.55  
>   Residual                     448.18  
>
> VarCorr(m1)
>  Groups           Name        Std.Dev.
>  soil_cluster:Rep (Intercept)   0.00  
>  Rep              (Intercept) 217.24  
>  Residual                     445.72
> ```

To get around this problem I have excluded Rep with the idea that the main variability is already accounted in the soil_cluster. Unfortunately the models are still singular.

The questions is:

Can I accept the result of a singular fitted model?
If not (as I believe), what can I do in order to fix the model?

Comment: What exactly is a "soil cluster"?

Comment: What's the result of `with(YMT, table(Rep, soil_cluster))`?

Comment: Maybe this FAQ from Ben Bolker (author of lme4) helps you further? http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions and apologies for my late reply. So:

Roland: a Soil_cluster is a cluster coming out from a k-medioids cluster analysis. This was carried out by taking into account 8 soil parameters at 3 different soil depths.

AdamO: 
       soil_cluster
       Rep  1  2
               1 10 40
               2 20 30
               3 10 40

BTW in this farm I have only 2 cluster while in the other farms I ended up with 4. Rep and Treat are the same.